# Align some HTML elements to the bottom of their parent

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a list of products that have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="myimg.jpg" />
    <div class="title">My Title</div>
    <div class="buttons"></div>
</div>
```

There are many of these parents next to each other. First I had an issue that they often would be of different height (due to the difference in the lengths of titles). I fixed that with using `display: flex;`, so now they are all of the same heights. However I need the `buttons` div to stick to the bottom of the `parent`, while the title and the image should stay where they are. So I'd prefer to have white space between the buttons and the previous children of `parent` rather than have white space at the bottom, below the buttons.

I tried to find a solution for this, but all the results lead to this CSS:

```
.parent { position: relative; }
.buttons { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
```

This solution does not work for me, because then buttons could overlap the title. So the best solution I could think of so far is to use bottom padding that is equal to the buttons' height:

```
.parent { display: flex; position: relative; padding-bottom: 100px; }
.buttons { position: absolute; bottom: 0; height: 100px; }
```

But I'm not sure if it's the best solution, because buttons' height might change or even be dynamic. Is there a better solution?

EDIT:

Here's a snippet to demonstrate the issue. First parent has 2 buttons, while the second has only one, this is intended - some products might have different number of buttons, that is one of the reasons why I can't use solution with `padding-bottom`.

```css
#wrap { display: flex; }
.parent { display: inline-block; position: relative; padding-bottom: 100px; width: 100px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px 20px 20px; margin: 0 5px 10px; }
.buttons { position: absolute; bottom: 0; height: 100px; }
.button-one { background: green; }
.button-two { background: red; }
.button-one, .button-two { margin: 15px 0 0; }
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="parent">
    <img src="myimg.jpg" />
    <div class="title">My Title</div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="button-one">Button one</div>
      <div class="button-two">Button two</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <img src="myimg.jpg" />
    <div class="title">My TitleMy TitleMy TitleMy TitleMy TitleMy TitleMy TitleMy TitleMy TitleMy TitleMy TitleMy TitleMy TitleMy TitleMy TitleMy TitleMy TitleMy TitleMy TitleMy Title</div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="button-one">Button one</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a farily okay solution - it's not that hard to change two values. However, you shouldn't use `px` as unit, for pretty much anything on a webpage. There are a couple exceptions, but buttons are not one of them. Use `em`or `%`.

Comment: Provide a working example (jsfiddle/codepen/snippet) with what you have

Comment: can you do a fiddle?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie, I use media queries for different resolutions and so far `px` proved to be more reliable than `em` and `%`, but thanks for the tip, I will investigate on that topic once more...

Comment: Added the snippet.

Comment: If you downvote, please provide feedback why you did that, otherwise it doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @DmitriyDemir so true

Comment: More reliable? For what?

Comment: For similar results on different devices and screen sizes. I'm not going to start a discussion on this though, because there's plenty of it already and it's not relevant to my question.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is add padding-bottom to your "title". Or if you can change the HTML structure that is the better option.

Try this layout in HTML.
[image]

Comment: Please check the snippet that I added. Adding padding to the title is equal to adding it to `.parent`, which I already mentioned as a possible, but probably not perfect solution. How would you suggest to change the HTML? I can only see a CSS issue here, but feel free to prove me wrong.

Comment: Please look at the layout I've just added.

Comment: I got what you mean, but I'm afraid that might cause more issues that it'd solve. The buttons should be in the same parent because the parent has a visible border, if I split the buttons and the rest of the content into separate rows then I'd need to align them horizontally and it'd probably look more messy than a fixed `padding-bottom`. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: Will posted If i got any solution, This is what I thought of for now.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the problem but i think You need to add a height and width

Comment: Height is dynamic and depends on the content, but you're right about the width. I tried to mention only relevant code, but hopefully it's more clear now with the snippet that I added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding`clear: both;` and `float: left;` to send it to the very bottom of its parent.

Like this:

```
.buttons { position: absolute; bottom: 0; height: 100px; clear: both; float: left; width: 100px; }
```

Comment: But these elements aren't floating... On which element should I apply `clear: both;`?

Comment: To what you want to go to the bottom of the parent element.

Comment: But that doesn't work, firstly because `clear` [works only with floating](http://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_class_clear.asp), secondly even if I make the elements float I can't make them stick to the bottom of the parent with `clear`. Please check the snippet to see the issue. Maybe I got you wrong, if so, please provide a snippet of what you mean.

Comment: I can't make it work like that, [here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a11sjchb/1/)

Comment: I don't think that your last update changes anything, because you also leave absolute positioning with `bottom: 0;`. The added `clear: both; float: left;` simply don't do anything in this example. You can try this on jsfiddler (I just did to make sure).